# Dynamic div content + retain last viewed div on browser backward

Tags: javascript, html

I am using dynamic div content and toggling between them on clicks, works well but is there a way to retain the last viewed div when the user clicks forward and backward on his browser? Thanks.

```
     <script>
          $(".settings").click(function() {
            var id = this.id;
            if ($("." + $(this).attr('rel')).css('display') == 'none') {
                $('.n_tab').hide();
                $('.p_tab').hide();
                ($("." + $(this).attr('rel')).show());
            }

        });
     </script>

     <div class="settings" rel="n_tab">
            <div class="title info_2_Title">
                Notifications</div>
     </div>
     <div class="settings" rel="p_tab">
            <div class="title info_2_Title">
                Privacy</div>
     </div>

     <div id="MasterContainer">
       <div class="n_tab" style="display: none;"> the N DIV </div>
       <div class="p_tab" style="display: none;"> the P DIV </div> 
     </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check out hisory.js https://github.com/balupton/History.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, but after fiddling ard with History.js, I still couldn't get it to work, in the end I used a cookie to store the state and then check it when the page with dynamic div loads.

```
 $(function() {
            var x = $.cookie('tab_cookie');
            ($(x).show());
            if (x == '.m_tab') {
                var btn = document.getElementById('<%= btnLoadm.ClientID %>');
                if (btn) btn.click();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a library like [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) to set that up. Internally it will use the `pushState` API, or fall back to url fragments if the browser doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an id to each tab and appending that in an object or array each time a div is selected.
Define an array `history = [];` outside the click event and in your click event something like

```
history.push($(this).id);
```

If you wanted to keep more detailed data you could use a json object and append to it.